# Unlock device (pattern) with monkeyrunner

Tags: monkeyrunner

Sorry if I do ask a question which has been asked before. I was searching a lot in this forum and via Google but couldn't find an answer.

I'm very new to Monkeyrunner and trying to solve the problem to automatically unlog my USB device which is secured with a pattern.

Is it possible to add a drag functionality with 2 different directions? A to B to C? A pattern usually needs at least 4 dots, which makes two directions for dragging.
I wrote this script which works fine observing the screen, but it interrupts in between which is not accepted by the phone:

```
print ("Unlocking screen.")
device.wake()
device.touch(400, 314, MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
device.drag((400, 314),(80, 635), 1,3)
device.drag((80, 635),(400, 635), 1,3)
device.touch(400, 635, MonkeyDevice.UP)
```

I hope someone is able to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have just published an article about [automated android testing using sikuli](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/01/automated-android-testing-using-sikuli.html) and the example was unlocking the emulator screen using the slide lock.

After reading your question I added another example of unlocking the emulator when it's locked by a pattern lock. Creating it would take you 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Diego for your reply! Is sikuli also working with USB devices?

Comment: I was watching some of the sikulis tutorials.. Please don't get me wrong but I don't think this piece of software will make me happy. It looks very simple and I'd prefer to learn more about "proper" test automations..
I also would like to get my question answered related to Monkeyrunner, otherwise I'll keep trying until I found a solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly solve your issue but may help you get further along and may help others.
I use this function to unlock a non-password protected device after a reboot:

```
def unlock(device):
    # Performs a swipe-up operation to unlock the device (no password)
    xStart = 0
    yStart = 1000
    device.touch(xStart, yStart, MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yCurrent = yStart - 100 * i
        device.touch(xStart, yCurrent, MonkeyDevice.MOVE)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    device.touch(xStart, yCurrent, MonkeyDevice.UP)
```